# Used Named Credentials to Call Web Service in OTHER Domain

Tags: apex, webservices, namedcredentials

I have a named credential for Microsoft Access Control Service, this named credential is Authenticated, so I need the token to call another web service that isn't in the same domain for example the URL to login is this : https://login.microsoftonline.com/********/v2.0 and I need to call a web service from other domain https://*********.org/api/Salesforce, both are different domains, to call the second web service I need the token generated for the named credential, Have any of you had this situation before?

Comment: What you have tried so far, what problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to connect to a web service, but I need to login first in outllok, then with the token consume the web service but this web service is in another domain, I can connect with named credential to outllok, but I can't get the token and send to the web service I need to consume.

Comment: are you using OAuth? are you getting any error while fetching the token?

Comment: yes I am using oauth2.0, but the problem is when I make the call out because with name credentials you call the named credential and to call the other web service you need to put the path, but in this case are different domains because of that I can not make the second call out.

Comment: create remote site setting for the second API, and call it using the authorization token.

Comment: I have the remote site settings, but I don't know to get the token, because the named credential don't give you the token explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108047/discussion-between-rahul-gawale-and-angello-camacho).

Comment: no, I need to get the token from the name credential to call another web service alocate in other domain, that is the problem.

Comment: You can't extract the token from a Named Credential, it acts as a runtime proxy.

Comment: So is no way to make this with named credentials, right?

Comment: If the endpoint supports a bearer token and the specific type/flavor of token can be negotiated via Named Credential, then it will work, otherwise no.

Comment: Yes the second call out asked for a bearing token, but how can I get the token?